# Discovery of Hystrix endpoints in Kubernetes (etcd)?

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, hystrix, etcd, turbine

We're migrating to Kubernetes and many of our services are using [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) which expose a stream of server sent event data consumed by [Turbine](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine) and visualized by a [Hystrix Dashboard](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-dashboard). I'd like to implement a service discovery plugin to Turbine which auto discovers our Hystix streams running on Kubernetes.

1. Would it be a good idea to use [labels](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/labels.md) for this? I.e. define a label that includes the path to the hystrix stream for each pod using Hystrix?
2. If labels are not a good idea, what would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I created a little project to address it.
essentially I implemented a hystric instance discovery class to work with kubernetes services.
You can find my project [here](https://github.com/raffaelespazzoli/hystrix-kuberneters-instance-discovery).

This projects is in its infancy so bugs are likely. Feedback it welcome.

Thanks
Raffaele

Comment: Thanks. I actually have this working as well, it's just that I want to avoid state. But currently I think it's invetable if you don't use polling.

Comment: @joahn, not sure what you mean by avoid state. My approach is to use a selector to select a group of pods that generate the stream. There is no state anywhere, if the pods change, the configuration adapts. It polls kubernetes master for the list of pods.

Comment: I don't have too much experience with Turbine 1 (I'm using Turbine 2) but how is the instance list refreshed in your code? I can only see that you poll Kubernetes once? What happens when a pod is stopped and thus needs to be removed from the insance list or if a new pod is being created and needs to be added?

Comment: @Johan, the code that you see is called every minute by turbine, that is how the pod list is refreshed. I tried to build it for turbine2, but got stuck, it looked like not all maven dependencies are published (yet).

Comment: Oh then it'll definitely work but I don't think Turbine 2 does that. You return an Observable with StreamAction's which consists of an URL and a whether the URL was ADDED or REMOVED. Turbine2 is in Maven central (but unfortunately not the version that supports basic auth that I'm using and that's preventing me from open sourcing it). Maybe we should collaborate on GitHub? :)

Comment: I'd be happy to collaborate. What do I need to do to enable you to work on my github project? Sorry I'm not familiar with the process.

Answer (score 0):

How about making Hystrix a Kubernetes service?Kubernetes has two suggested ways to discover services: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#discovering-services

Comment: Hmm I don't think that would work. I need to connect to each individual pod since I'm interested in the stream for each pod and not for a service.

Comment: a "headless" service does not use a VIP, but still gives you DNS-based grouping.

Comment: you can get the address of pod by querying the apiserver for the service's endpoints, the url will be <master url>/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/endpoints/<service name>. Also note that the endpoints are dynamic.